# Convergence value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^a}{n!}$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I tried to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^a}{n!}$ ($a\in\mathbb{R}$) is convergent, and I think I have done it by ratio test, but I couldn't find its convergence value. I could find that for $a=1 $ it is convergent to $e$ or for $a=0$ it converges to $e-1$. I need help for finding convergence value for every $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Thanks.

Comment: For integers the answer is well known, though I don't think it is at all obvious.  The answer, for $\alpha = k\in \mathbb N$, is $B_k\times e$, where $B_k$ is the $k^{th}$ Bell number (the number of partitions of $k$ letters).  See [Dobinski's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula)

Comment: why you think that it converges to some value that can be represented easily?

Comment: @Masacroso I could find some values which are easily represented using wolfram alpha, and I thought may be there is some formula for these values.

Comment: @lulu Thank you!